# TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable : django error

Tags: python, django, function, typeerror

I am creating an API for polls app and I stuck into this **error**:

> error.TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable : django
>   error my models:

How can I deal with it? It seems like there is no error in the code.

**Code:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, related_name='choices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text


class Vote(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, related_name='votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("poll", "voted_by")
```

**my views:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Poll

def polls_list(request):
    MAX_OBJECTS = 20
    polls = Poll.objects.all()[:MAX_OBJECTS]
    data = {"results": list(polls.values("question", "created_by__username", "pub_date"))}
    return JsonResponse(data)


def polls_detail(request, pk):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=pk)
    data = {"results": {
        "question": poll.question,
        "created_by": poll.created_by.username,
        "pub_date": poll.pub_date
     }}
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Show the traceback so we can see where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead as I'm not sure how well all works with slicing:

```
def polls_list(request):
    MAX_OBJECTS = 20
    polls = Poll.objects.values("question", "created_by__username", "pub_date")
    data = {"results": list(polls[:MAX_OBJECTS])}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```